# How to get collection of ActiveRecord object from another collection of ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord collection:

```
current_user.memberships
=> [#<Membership id: 20, student_id: 19, group_id: 4, state: "accepted", created_at: "2015-04-02 09:58:45", updated_at: "2015-04-02 09:59:42">,
 #<Membership id: 19, student_id: 18, group_id: 4, state: "accepted", created_at: "2015-03-19 14:01:58", updated_at: "2015-03-20 13:27:38">,
 #<Membership id: 17, student_id: 16, group_id: 4, state: "accepted", created_at: "2015-03-19 13:42:38", updated_at: "2015-03-20 13:28:38">,
 #<Membership id: 16, student_id: 15, group_id: 4, state: "accepted", created_at: "2015-03-19 13:39:15", updated_at: "2015-03-19 13:39:15">,
 #<Membership id: 15, student_id: 14, group_id: 4, state: "accepted", created_at: "2015-03-19 13:28:12", updated_at: "2015-03-19 13:28:12">,
 #<Membership id: 14, student_id: 13, group_id: 4, state: "accepted", created_at: "2015-03-19 13:26:44", updated_at: "2015-03-19 13:26:44">,
 #<Membership id: 13, student_id: 12, group_id: 4, state: "accepted", created_at: "2015-03-19 13:19:05", updated_at: "2015-03-19 13:19:05">]
```

I want to get collection of groups (unique) from the `current_user.memberships`. In this case that would be just one `Group`:

```
#<Group id: 4, school_id: 6538, name: "Klasa 1a", created_at: "2015-03-19 13:19:05", updated_at: "2015-03-19 13:19:05", user_id: 13, tutor_user_id: nil, tutor_email: nil>
```

In pseudocode that would be something like `current_user.memberships.groups.unique`. How can I do that?

My models:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :memberships, through: :groups
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: Whats wrong with current_user.groups?

Comment: Actually, your associations appear to be mangled. It seems to me, that user needs to have many `membership`s, and then have many `group`s through `membership`s. Am I right?

Comment: @Coderhs I want to get only those `groups` of `current_user`, that have `memberships` with state `waiting`. `current_user.groups` gives me all groups that belong to the user.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user.groups` is the collection of unique groups that `belong_to` the user in your model setting.